# sbt-uglify compressOptions not taking?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, uglifyjs, uglifyjs2, xsbt-web-plugin

I have been trying to add in sbt-uglify, which has worked out through trial and error. I find the documentation lacking and Google results not good. This plugin is based on UglifyJS.

The issue I am having is the fact that it drops unreachable code and unused functions/variables. This will be well enough if this was my code but I have to maintain legacy JS and can't have side effects of dropped stuff.

The code I used is `Seq("unused: false", "dead_code: false")` but have also tried `Seq("unused: false, dead_code: false")`

If someone knows if I am missing something please let me know.

Helpful Links:
https://github.com/sbt/sbt-uglify

Here is a sample project if need be, but it is not of my own: https://github.com/nonameplum/play-uglify-test

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Seq("unused=false", "dead_code=false")`

The setting is passed directly to UglifyJS2 as command-line arguments. Uglify expects options in the form `foo=bar` according to their documentation:

https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#compressor-options